# Aptana Javascript how to run a single javascript program in aptana

Tags: javascript, aptana

all I would like to do is run this simple program in Aptana to see if it works, but it doesnt even show up.
I used the Javascript Template from Aptana's selection. here is the program.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
function verse (verseNum) {
    var lines = "";
    if (verseNum ==1 ) {
        lines = "One thing I dont know why...";
    } else if (verseNum == 1 {
        lines = "All I know time is a valuable thing...";
    } else {
        lines = "NoLyrics";
    }
    return (lines);
}
alert (verse(1));
alert (verse(2));
</script>
```

When I run the program, it shows a blank webpage. I am sure it is a very simple mistake, probably completely wrong format. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you console.log() || alert() || document.write() something?
try console.log(verse(2));

Comment: I put 
    alert(verse(1));

sorry, i forgot to include that, but still nothing shows up when i run it. just a blank page

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a parenthesis, added here:

```
} else if (verseNum == 1) {
```

You need to use your browser's console to discover such errors, although I'm surprised that Aptana doesn't indicate it as well.

Comment: Thanks, i corrected that, I also added the alert command, to the functions, but still nothing is showing up but a blank page when i run the program

Comment: works now actually, thank you! i forgot one more paranthesis lol